# Covert Linq to Expression Tree

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-objects

Need help in converting this linq query to Expression Tree

```
Dim query = (From _row In table.Rows
                 Group _row By vGroup = _row("VENDOR")
                 Into VendorGroup = Group
            Select New With {
                Key vGroup,
                    .PI = VendorGroup.Sum(Function(r) r("PI")),
                    .ST = VendorGroup.Sum(Function(r) r("ST")),
                    .IS = VendorGroup.Sum(Function(r) r("IS")),
                    .RR = VendorGroup.Sum(Function(r) r("RR"))
           }).ToList
```

Comment: It makes no sense at all to convert a list to an expression tree, at all.  What do you possibly mean by that?  Also, don't tag vb questions as C# questions, it's a VB question.

Comment: @Servy I'm working on a logic to pass the Group by Column name and the Aggregate columns name dynamically. So, thought of forming a dynamic linq with Expression tree.

Comment: You don't really need to do that at all.  You can already get row values based on a string column name; just have a variable that you close over with the column name(s) to use, rather than hard coding them.  There's no need for expressions to do that.

Comment: @servy I need to pass even the aggregate functions (Count, Average,..) dynamically.

Comment: @Servy Okay. Since you asked for it, I have a Collection of Aggregate columns with their respective functions to perform on dynamic groups. Now I need to loop through the collection and frame the expression tree to handle these dynamically. How do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can *try* converting to `IQueryable` then pulling out the `Expression` property:

```
Dim expression = (From _row In table.Rows
             Group _row By vGroup = _row("VENDOR")
             Into VendorGroup = Group
        Select New With {
            Key vGroup,
                .PI = VendorGroup.Sum(Function(r) r("PI")),
                .ST = VendorGroup.Sum(Function(r) r("ST")),
                .IS = VendorGroup.Sum(Function(r) r("IS")),
                .RR = VendorGroup.Sum(Function(r) r("RR"))
       }).AsQueryable()
         .Expression
```

but the expression you get back may vary depending on the query provider you're using.

Comment: +1  -i did not know that - i'm flabbergasted at myslef, given the hoops i've gone thor to identify the expression in the past!! doh